# Retrieving .NET session variables from client side script

Tags: javascript, .net, session

I'm trying this with javascript, but it's possible there is an easier/better way.

I have a .NET application that sets a Session Variable on the code behind. I also have HTML files in the website that are created on the fly and are static, but should be able to access these sessions just the same (via javascript most likely). Meaning, if there is not a session set, I want the HTML page to redirect back to the main .aspx page.

With the following, it always gives me an empty string, even though the session is recognized on the .aspx pages, any way to overcome this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(){
        var someSession = '<%= Session("user") %>';
        alert(someSession)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can't access the variables from HTML, you need to access them via ASP.NET through a page or service.  Since you want to use them in JavaScript, you might consider writing a service to pull the user session variable from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static html pages don't execute any server code.  They are simply served up as-is.

```
<%= Session("user") %>
```

by definition involves executing server-side code.  That's why it works in the aspx pages and not the html.

The way to overcome this is to convert the html pages to aspx pages, or use an Ajax query to call back to the server and get the session info from a web service or other method.

Comment: I tried placing the code in a .asp page and still got the same results. Any ideas there? From test.asp:   `<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething(){
   var someSession = '<%= Session("user") %>';
   alert(someSession)
  }
 </script>
<body onload="doSomething();">

</body>
</html>`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but as @r584 said it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

As has been already said it must be an active page and the correct code is:

```
var sessionValue = '<%= Session["user"] %>';
```